Chapter title style
I found on internet a template for thesis, but I don't like the chapter titles. I really want to make them look like as in the picture below.

Do you know how to make it?
I've tried with this (minimal reproducible example):
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for text color
\usepackage{lipsum}


% Redefine the \chapter command
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Huge\bfseries\textcolor{red}{\thechapter}\par\nobreak  % Extra large, bold, and red chapter number
        \vskip 2\p@
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}

But it is not the style I am looking for and I can't make the title number bigger.

You can borrow the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591058/36296 (adjust colour and font to your taste):
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for text color
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
 \usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
 \fontsize{100}{100}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
 \selectfont%                  % activate font
}
\colorlet{chapnumcol}{red!75!black}  % color for chapter number

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
{\filleft\bfseries}
{\filleft\chapnumfont\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}
{-24pt}
{\Huge}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\filright\bfseries}
{\filright}
{-24pt}
{\Huge}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}


